# Why am I getting 'Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException' in PM Console when I try and run my 'update-database'

Tags: sql, database

Everytime I try and update my SQL Db I am getting an error '*Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException*' directly in the PM console. I think it's something being redundant and I believe it's related to an **ApplicationDbContext<>** statement but I have also referenced another students code and it seems to be identical. All Db sets are present as far as I can tell nothing has been changed with db names and the connection string looks correct.

my connection string in my config:

````
  </connectionStrings>```


...and here is my seed method for roles (and my only one currently implemented)




protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists(RoleNames.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(RoleNames.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR));

            }
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists(RoleNames.ROLE_PROJECTMANAGER))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(RoleNames.ROLE_PROJECTMANAGER));
            }
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists(RoleNames.ROLE_DEVELOPER))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(RoleNames.ROLE_DEVELOPER));

            }
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists(RoleNames.ROLE_USER))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(RoleNames.ROLE_USER));
            }

            ApplicationUser userA = userManager.FindByEmail("ashortnm88@gmail.com");

            if (userA == null)
            {
                userA = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "ashortnm88@gmail.com",
                    Email = "ashortnm88@gmail.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                IdentityResult userResult = userManager.Create(userA, "Abc&123!");
                if (userResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    var result = userManager.AddToRole(userA.Id, RoleNames.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR);
                }
            }
            ApplicationUser userB = userManager.FindByEmail("DemoPM@gmail.com");

            if (userB == null)
            {
                userB = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "DemoPM@gmail.com",
                    Email = "DemoPM@gmail.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                IdentityResult userResult = userManager.Create(userB, "Abc&123!");
                if (userResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    var result = userManager.AddToRole(userB.Id, RoleNames.ROLE_PROJECTMANAGER);
                }
            }
            ApplicationUser userC = userManager.FindByEmail("DemoDev@gmail.com");

            if (userC == null)
            {
                userC = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "DemoDev@gmail.com",
                    Email = "DemoDev@gmail.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                IdentityResult userResult = userManager.Create(userC, "Abc&123!");
                if (userResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    var result = userManager.AddToRole(userC.Id, RoleNames.ROLE_DEVELOPER);
                }
            }
            ApplicationUser userD = userManager.FindByEmail("DemoUser@gmail.com");

            if (userD == null)
            {
                userD = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "DemoUser@gmail.com",
                    Email = "DemoUser@gmail.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                IdentityResult userResult = userManager.Create(userD, "Abc&123!");
                if (userResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    var result = userManager.AddToRole(userD.Id, RoleNames.ROLE_USER);
                }
            }

            //TICKET STASUES
            context.TicketStatus.AddOrUpdate(
                t => t.Name,
                new TicketStatus { Name = "New" },
                new TicketStatus { Name = "Open" },
                new TicketStatus { Name = "Resolved" },
                new TicketStatus { Name = "Archived" });

            //TICKET TYPES
            context.TicketTypes.AddOrUpdate(
               t => t.Name,
               new TicketType { Name = "A" },
               new TicketType { Name = "B" },
               new TicketType { Name = "C" },
               new TicketType { Name = "D" });


            //TICKET PRIORITY
            context.TicketPriorities.AddOrUpdate(
               t => t.Name,
               new TicketPriority { Name = "High"},
               new TicketPriority { Name = "Low" },
               new TicketPriority { Name = "Medium" });



            //TICKET


            context.SaveChanges();



        }
        public class RoleNames
        {
            public const string ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR = "Administrator";
            public const string ROLE_PROJECTMANAGER = "Project Manager";
            public const string ROLE_DEVELOPER = "Developer";
            public const string ROLE_USER = "Submittee";
        }



    }
````

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: yes and it seems to have an issue with this line now; ` public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }`

Comment: What do you mean "seems to have an issue?" Please describe the symptoms exactly, rather than your conclusions about them.

Comment: I meant it's where the error occurred. I fixed the issue; it was passing data cyclically because of a misplaced instance of ApplicationDbContext; which is hard to pinpoint and or debug.